# How to use custom dataset generators with TPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kaggle, tpu

My dataset is large (around 13gb). I have a hdf5 file of the dataset and i'm using a custom generator to load batches from the dataset. My model runs fine on Kaggle GPU but when i switch to TPU i'm getting an error. Below is my generator function and the error i receive when running model.fit.

```
def generate_data():

while True: # Loop forever so the generator never terminates
    
    for _ in range(0, num_samples, BATCH_SIZE):
        # Get the samples you'll use in this batch
        offset=np.random.randint(num_samples)
        X_train = hdf5_file['data'][offset]
        X_train=X_train.transpose(1,2,0)
        X_train=X_train.astype(np.float32)
        X_train=(X_train-127.5)/127.5
        X_train = cv2.resize(X_train, dsize=(IMG_SHAPE[1],IMG_SHAPE[1]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        X_train = np.array(X_train)
        
        #yield the next training batch
        yield X_train
```

Here's the code to generate tf datasets from the generator fn.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate_data, (tf.float32))
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE,drop_remainder=True)
```

Now here's the error i receive when i run model.fit with the above dataset.

```
TypeError: in user code:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py:174 run  **
    return self.extended.tpu_run(fn, args, kwargs, options)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py:867 tpu_run
    return func(args, kwargs)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py:916 tpu_function
    maximum_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape([None] * rank)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'
```

As i mentioned the code works fine on GPU without any modification. What should i do to make it work on TPU?

Comment: As far as I know - `from_generator()` doesn't work with TPU because it uses numpy functions

Comment: Is there any other alternative? For loding data batchwise since the ram cannot hold the entire dataset.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870656/file-system-scheme-local-not-implemented-in-google-colab-tpu

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried defining shape of an output in `from_generator()` function?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate_data, 
                                                                  output_types=(tf.dtypes.float32),
                                                                  output_shapes=(output_shape))`

but i'm not sure that would help