# UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle, tpu

I am getting an error while implementing TensorFlow in TPU

```
UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: '1.png')
```

I know this question has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870656/file-system-scheme-local-not-implemented-in-google-colab-tpu) but my issue is different,
I am getting this error when I do

```
for i, j in train_dataset.take(3):
    print(i,j)
```

It works with `train_dataset.take(3)`

Here are my functions

```
def decode(img,image_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)):
    bits = tf.io.read_file(img)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    image = tf.image.resize(image, image_size)
    
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, seed=2020)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, seed=2020)
    image = tf.image.random_crop(image,size=[IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3],seed=2020 )
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image,max_delta=0.5 )
    image = tf.image.rot90(image)
    return image

def decode_image(img,labels=None ):
    if labels is None:
        return decode(img)
    else:
        return decode(img),labels 

train_image=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train.iloc[:,0],train.iloc[:,1::] ))
train_dataset=train_image.map(decode_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO).repeat().shuffle(512).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTO)
test_image=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test.iloc[:,0]))
test_dataset=test_image.map(decode_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

How should I resolve it?

It might an issue with the path. SO I am adding how is set path
This is how the directory looks like

```
weights
images
-train
--train
---train
----img1
----img2
---csv
-val
--val
---img1
```

When I run

```
GCS_DS_PATH = KaggleDatasets().get_gcs_path('images')
!gsutil ls $GCS_DS_PATH
```

I got following

```
gs://kds-aab923e1c9bc934f088881f1e537365b8f18fe192b3b3dc14e272a37/train/
gs://kds-aab923e1c9bc934f088881f1e537365b8f18fe192b3b3dc14e272a37/val/
```

This is how my paths are set

```
def train_format_path(st):
    return GCS_DS_PATH + '/train/train/train/' + st 

def test_format_path(st):
    return GCS_DS_PATH + '/val/val/' + st 

train_paths = train.ID.apply(train_format_path).values
test_paths = test.ID.apply(test_format_path).values
```

With `train_paths[0]`
I got

```
'gs://kds-aab923e1c9bc934f088881f1e537365b8f18fe192b3b3dc14e272a37/train/train/train/1.png'
```

Comment: @TakhaAnswar - Your picture is different from the link you provided, (I do not know about if this is any wrong or if it does work) but - check, can re-try this at the same picture, but as another extension? maybe the extension in the link you provided: jpg instead of your "1.png" ("1.jpg" maybe could work?)

Comment: yes, i know, but mostly stackoverflow mods refers to similar post, so telling in advance that my issue is different. and its `.png`

Comment: @TalhaAnswar Yeah; No worries what so ever! :)  I just wondered if you have tried another extension? (does .jpg work - or is it the same problem there too?) sorry if I was unclear, will follow this post.

Comment: so, you are saying, first to convert data to jpg?

Comment: Well, yeah - or at least begin (as number 1) to just rename the file "1.png" to "1.jpg" and try it again,  if that does not work;  You can try as you yourself suggested - convert the png to jpg, and then try it  (This is what I would've done in this scenario)

Comment: yes, i have. It might the issue with path, so I added how I set path

Comment: Okay, (For me it's really late, so I'll go) but ill just say that; I will try this on my front tomorrow, since one of my friends (not so long ago) actually had a very similar problem, (was also on kaggle, surprisingly!). For now,  //Best wishes from Sweden!

Comment: I don't quite understand.  You say your problem is with `train_dataset.take(3)`, but I don't see that in your code.  And are you saying that this call works unless you put it in a `for` loop and then simply print the resulting pair of values from each iteration?  If so, then there's only one explanation I can think of that makes sense.

Comment: yes, it work with out loop and did not work with loop. and if let for a while I ignore it, I got the same error at 'model.fit()` function

Comment: If it's really that simple, then the only explanation I can think of is "back pressure".  That is, in the absence of the `for` loop asking for values, there is code that isn't running because it isn't being asked to provide values.  I know this concept better in Java, but I can see that Python "generators" might have this same characteristic.  That's the only explanation I can see making sense.  The only one, which is pretty wild, is that calling `print()` on the values somehow changes the iteration.  That is possible if the `__repr__` method of some object being printed has a side effect.

Comment: nope, i dont think it has to do with print. because of fork some one notebook and did the same and it worked

Comment: ah...ok.  You might try assigning the result to a variable and then converting that to a list (it may be a list already, but you want to make sure).  That should insure that all values are generated.  If that fails also, then it has to be a backpressure thing.

Comment: I noticed that you have:

`train_image=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train.iloc[:,0],train.iloc[:,1::] ))`

but it looks like your changes to the path should work. Does it work if you replace `train.iloc...` with `train_paths.iloc...`?

Comment: @AllenWang thanks. look like this is the issue

Comment: @Talha Anwar, Is your issue resolved after changing `train.iloc` with `train_paths.iloc` ?

Comment: @TFer2 yes, I added the solution in the comment as suggested by AllenWang

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Allen Wang, the solution is to use `train_paths` instead of train to pass images.

This is what I have changes to make it work

```
    train_image=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_paths,train.iloc[:,1::] ))
    train_dataset=train_image.map(decode_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO).repeat().shuffle(512).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTO)
    test_image=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_paths))
    test_dataset=test_image.map(decode_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTO).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```