# Google Colab with TPU, unable to read images from Google Drive white fitting model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use the Google Colab TPU to train a neural network after loading from a GDrive folder mounted on `/content/drive/`, this is the code:

```py
dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    TRAIN_PATH,
    image_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
    color_mode=COLOR_MODE.keyword,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
)

try:
  resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
  tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
  tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
  print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))

  strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
except ValueError:
  print("TPU not found using default strategy")
  strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()

# TODO: check if creating the model inside this scope is correct
with strategy.scope():
  model = CreateModel()

early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    patience=8,
)

save_best_model = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    LOCAL_MODELS_FOLDER,
    monitor='val_loss',
    save_best_only=True,
    save_weights_only=True,
)


history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    callbacks=[
        early_stop,
        save_best_model
    ],
    verbose=1,
)
```

When I run I get this error:

```
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

9 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNIMPLEMENTED:  File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: '/content/drive/Shareddrives/[...]/file0001.png')
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
[...]
```

I can't find a solution to this unneedful problem, some say it's bc I've to use the python's read instead of tf.io but I've literally 0 clues of what that means.

Any hints on how to solve?

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870656/file-system-scheme-local-not-implemented-in-google-colab-tpu/62881833#62881833) but it's very cryptic

Answer (score 1):

Mount the google Drive first then double check the google drive path where you saved your images, e.g.,

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')  # Put your google drive path here.
```